# Recommend few specific command line utilities. (Windows)

Tags: windows, open-source, command-line, xml, text-search

Can you recommend me small command line utilities for Windows that can do these things? I prefer open-source ones. No Powershell please.

1. Utility that will download a file when specified URL, HTTPS support will be good.
2. Utility that will find specific strings or values in XML file.
3. Utility that will find and replace specific lines in text, Unicode and Unix line ending support will be good (ASCII and DOS line ending support too).
4. Utility that copy files, just basic functionality of XCOPY and ROBOCOPY.
5. DPInst alternative, something that will install drivers to system. I've seen one, know it exist, just can't remember name and can't even find something useful.
6. Utility that will check SHA-1 hash of file.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: I don't get #4: why don't you use COPY/XCOPY/ROBOCOPY?

Comment: Because it will be used for installation package, and some stupid people (i don't know how) don't have xcopy or robocopy in "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32".
Classic "copy" is not useful to me

Comment: Shouldn't this be split into different questions?

Comment: Once you have the driver you can install it like this:
     DISM.exe /Image:C:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:d:\Drivers\ /Recurse

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don’t think so. There just would be five identical sets of answers (Python / Cygwin / NSIS / etc) for five different questions.

Answer (score 4):

I have done all of those things that you require using [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It is a scriptable installer generator for Windows, but it can be scripted to be used for any purpose really.

The strong points of this installer is that it is very efficient, small size, very portable across Windows versions, tons of plugins for any purpose you can think of. The weak point that I can think of is that it is pretty difficult to learn in the beginning, even you have programming experience.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are looking for [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/packages/package_list.html) to get a full featured GNU environment, so that you would have:

<sub>> 1. Utility that will download a file when specified URL, HTTPS support will be good.</sub>

GNU Wget.

<sub>> 2. Utility that will find specific strings or values in XML file.</sub>

I am not sure, what ‘find strings in XML’ is, but Cygwin distribution include, for instance, `xmlstarlet` to process XML.

<sub>> 3. Utility that will find and replace specific lines in text, Unicode and Unix line ending support will be good (ASCII and DOS line ending support too).</sub>

GNU AWK + iconv in order to handle different encodings. (Sed does not support setting line separators, afaik.)

<sub>> 4. Utility that copy files, just basic functionality of `XCOPY` and `ROBOCOPY`.</sub>

`cp` from GNU Coreutils. `rsync` if you want more.

<sub>> 6. Utility that will check SHA-1 hash of file.</sub>

`sha1sum` from GNU Coreutils

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you are looking for, but it is the right answer IMHO.

Python

You can write some amazing python scripts and it is not hard to find a Python script that can do each of the items you mention.  Another advantage... you can customize each to work exactly the way you like.  Don't underestimate the power of Python.  You can even build fully function GUI applications as well as web interfaces with it.

Comment: Ok, how much space will it take?

Comment: 50-250 MB depending on which modules you load.  Modules are the additional opensource components that will do the specialized tasks.  I recommend installing python 2.7 because there is more info available for 2.7 instead of 3.